# assign multiple arrays to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I got multiple arrays and want to assign them to dataframe columns and store it to a list:

```
temp =  pd.date_range(date_from, date_to)

for index in range(len(a_id)):
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    df['date'] = temp
    df['system_id'] = a_id[index]
    df['simulated_yield_in_kWh'] = pr_daily[:, index]
    df['gloabl_irradiance_tilted_in_kWh_per_m2'] = rad_daily[:, index]
    finalDataframes.append(df)
```

The problem is the arrays got different lengths. pr_daily and rad_daily are of length 342 and a_id is of length 1. How can I assign the id to all fields of the dataframe? Currently it's filled with NaN.

Also I can't assign the date cause it's of length 344.

EDIT: I solved the second problem by trimming:

```
temp =  pd.date_range(date_from, date_to)[:len(pr_daily)]
```

Comment: `pd.DataFrame({'date' : temp, ... )` then just add in the new column with a simple broadcast statement

Comment: I am confused..if a_id is of length 1 then what is the for loop for?

Comment: It's not of length 1. It's of the length of systems I got. And that's a variable range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply do

```
df['system_id] = a_id
```

It will automatically broadcast to the proper length.

In case a_id is a length 1 array, do `df['system_id'] =  a_id[0]`

Comment: I tried this, but getting the error "ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index". Also I need the indexed value of the a_id array.

Comment: @TimoK you need to make it a scalar for it to work. Do `df['system_id'] = a_id[0]`